# How to serarch for multiple values in a array where some values are optional

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a better way to search in a php array where one or more neeldes matches the haystack?
This code work, but is not scalable...

```php
if(in_array('administrator', $user->roles) || in_array('manager', $user->roles)) {
   $trusted = TRUE;
}
```

I know that I can use an array inside *in_array*, but it only seem to return true if all needles match.
Eg:

```php
if(in_array(array('administrator','manager'), $user->roles) ) {
   $trusted = TRUE;
}
```

This will return true only if both needles (administrator and manager) match the haystack ($user->roles).
Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Have you looked at `preg_grep`? : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php - it allows you to match array values against a RegExp pattern.

Comment: Thanks, but using preg_grep feels like a guarantee to get migraine :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for `array_intersect`. Although it's convenient it's also a little bit wasteful (and thus arguably inelegant) so whether to use it or not is your call.

```
$trusted = (bool)array_intersect($user->roles, ['administrator', 'manager']);
```

I 'm casting the resulting array to a bool because it fits the semantics of your example (if any of the roles is found the result will be non-empty and be converted to `true`).

Comment: Threw me for a second the PHP 5.4 short array syntax - still not used to seeing it outside JS-land normally.

Comment: That solved my question, thanks. I was not aware of the "(bool)array_intersect()" syntax, using bool outside the function in that way. Interesting...